# changing an image using a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, button

I'm trying to create a program where it will move through a set of images by using changing the number in the array to the corresponding number to which the file is saved as e.g.

coolimg.1.jpg
coolimg.2.jpg
coolimg.3.jpg
etc...

this is what i've tried and im having no luck with it, i think my logic is right by adding one to the counter which would change the array number.

any help would be great.
thanks

```
<html>
<title>Image Array Demo</title>
<img id="myImg" 
src="coolimg.1.jpg" 
width ='100' 
height='100'/>

<button id='buttonId' 
onClick='change_image(event, this)'> 
click me </button>

<script>
var myImages = [1, 2]
var img_index = 0;
var imgId = "myImg";
var buttonId = 'buttonId'
//document.getElementById(buttonId).onClick = change_image();

function change_image() {
    img_index++;
        this.src = "coolimg." + myImages[img_index] + ".jpg"

    if (img_index == myImages.length){
        img_index = 0;
    }


}

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line (which is not correct also) `document.getElementById(buttonId).onClick = change_image();` Because you are already assigning event handler in your html i.e. `<button id='buttonId' onClick='change_image()'>`. Better pass event and element object like this

```
<button id='buttonId' onClick='change_image(event, this)'>
```

Apart from this, in `change_image` function you are referring to variable `me`, I suppose it should be the image object, replace it with `this`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vppkuawt/)

Since I could not show demo with static images like img.1.jpg img.2.jpg, I've used some random images, which changes onclick of the button.

```
var myImages = ['http://data.whicdn.com/images/12921361/superthumb.jpg',
            'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/dd/c2/b5/ddc2b51faa1955195f64cedddb72cfcb.jpg'];

var img_index = 0;
function change_image() {

    //here "this" will point to button, 
    //the element which is clicked ie event occurred.

    //but we need image, so get it by using below statement
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

    img_index = ++img_index % 2; //replace 2 with number of images
    img.src = myImages[img_index];
}
```

Examples are similar, but try to get the point. You just need to get the image object using `document.getElementById` and using that change the `src` attribute. Finally, `img_index = ++img_index % 2;` this logic will change from 0,1,0,1... to get next input in array (when it reaches end, it starts from beginning by using `%` operator).

Comment: i've changed the code in my question to what you have suggested but im not having any luck with it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought onclick of image, you wanted to change another image, but you need this action for on button click. I'll update my answer based on that.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope you will get the point and change your code accordingly using that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
document.getElementById("me").src = "coolimg." + myImages[img_index] + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Where would i put that Oliver?

Comment: in place of this.src = "coolimg." + myImages[img_index] + ".jpg"